# How to move gitlab-ci.yml file outside of repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The idea of having the CI configuration in repository is ridiculus.

Lets say I want to contribute to https://github.com/laravel/laravel
I have a local gitlab based CI for testing my changes.

The issue is adding `.gitlab-ci.yml` into the repository is ridiculus for at least 2 reasons:

1. Lets tell `100 000+` people that my gitlab server is at `my-gitlab.foo.com`, my jenkins is at `my-jenkins.bar.com` and to trigger a build you must `POST my-build-server.baz.com/trigger/abc-123`, that is definately not going to cause lot of people trying to hack my servers.
2. 99% of project maintainers is going to reject a pull request containing a stupid `.gitlab-ci.yml` file pointing to some private build servers

So knowing that `.gitlab-ci.yml` MUST NOT be placed inside the repository, my question is where can I put it, so it will still work (I will still be able to run certain scripts on push and/or trigger jenkins or any other build server)?

The best I was able to find was to place `.gitlab-ci.yml` in another project and then place a trigger in `.gitlab-ci.yml` inside the application, that solves #1 but still does not solve #2, and it makes the system too complicated

Answer (score 2):

How about placing the GitLab file in another project and updating the project settings to use that file?

> you can specify an alternate filename path, including locations outside the project.
>
> - [Pipeline settings docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file)